# Concatenate lines to a list in text file

Tags: bash, text, awk

I have this txt file which contains probabilities of certain sections of a audio files.

Example:

```
K-0_0_1_0_1_0_1_1_8547  [
  0 0 1 ]
K-0_0_1_0_1_0_1_1_23086  [
  1 1.191074e-27 1.574905e-26 ]
K-0_0_1_0_1_0_1_1_23781  [
  0 0 1 ]
K-0_0_1_0_1_0_1_1_3732  [
  0 0 1 ]
K-0_0_1_0_1_0_1_1_13964  [
  0 0 1 ]
K-0_0_1_0_1_0_1_1_3098  [
  1 0 0 ]
K-0_0_1_0_1_0_1_1_8296  [
  0 0 1 ]
K-0_0_1_0_1_0_1_1_1780  [
  0 0 1 ]
K-0_0_1_0_1_0_1_1_21968  [
  1 1.377321e-38 0 ]
```

In which the desired output should be

```
K-0_0_1_0_1_0_1_1 [
0 0 1 
1 0 0
0 0 1
0 0 1
0 0 1
0 0 1
1 1.377321e-38 0
1 1.191074e-27 1.574905e-26
0 0 1 ]
```

The input file is structured like this

```
filename_pieces [ probability_1 probability_2 probability_3 ]
```

I would like to collect all the pieces of the filename in to one
combined list of the probabilities, in which the position are in ascending order.

So in the case up there should the combined list be structured with like this

```
_1780
_3098
_3732
and so on..
```

The way i've currently being doing this is using this script..

```
awk 'NF == 2{ match($1,/^[0-9]+(_[0-9]+){7}/); k = substr($1,RSTART,RLENGTH); next }
     { $NF=""; a[k]=a[k]"\n "$0 }
     END { for(i in a) printf "%s [%s ]\n\n",i,a[i] }'
```

But this doesn't seem to be fond of the `K-` in the front of the filename, which is kind of crucial..  Someway I can alter the script to work with this. The previous valid filename was just `0_0_1_0_1_0_1_1` so the numbers without the the `K-` infront.

Comment: So, what are your valid filenames? I see you require them to have 8 numbers separated with an underscore. What are valid prefixes (along `K-`)?

Comment: @randomir I've just added it.  but the valid filename is the the same name without the `K-` so just `0_0_1_0_1_0_1_1`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your script, but with added sorting by file part (the last number separated by an underscore) and combining by filename, the script looks like this (expanded to multiline for readability):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

NF == 2 {
    match($1, /_[0-9]+$/)
    filename = substr($1, 0, RSTART-1)
    part = substr($1, RSTART+1, RLENGTH)
    next
}

{ 
    $NF = ""
    all[filename][part] = $0
}

END {
    for (filename in all) {
        n = asorti(all[filename], sorted, "@ind_num_asc")
        printf "%s [", filename
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
            printf "\n%s", all[filename][sorted[i]]
        }
        print "]"
    }
}
```

First we store all parts in a 2-D array, organizing by filename and part number. In the end, for each file encountered, we sort by indices ascending (which are part numbers) and then print all parts for a file in order.

Running it on your sample input, we get:

```
$ awk -f join.awk audio
K-0_0_1_0_1_0_1_1 [
0 0 1 
1 0 0 
0 0 1 
0 0 1 
0 0 1 
0 0 1 
1 1.377321e-38 0 
1 1.191074e-27 1.574905e-26 
0 0 1 ]
```

Comment: it should though be the other way... It seems like the result is concatenated in ascending order instead of descending..

Comment: Oh, so do you want to order by ascending section id? Also, does your input text include multiple files, or always one?

Comment: It include multiple files... And some of them start with a `g-` instead of `K-`

Comment: Alright, I think I understand now what you need. Please have a look at my edited (new) answer.

Comment: Is there anything that determines the number of entries each line can have?

Comment: There are no limits set on the number of entries (probabilities in your question) each line may contain.